# How to use Delphi RTTI to get and set Record Values

Tags: delphi, rtti, delphi-xe

I'm attempting to use the enhanced RTTI features in Delphi XE or later,  to read and write objects to XML. So far I've been successful with integers, floats, strings, enumerated types, sets and classes but can't output or read records correctly. The problem seems to be getting an instance (pointer) to the record property.

```
//Outputs Properties To XML
procedure TMyBase.SaveToXML(node: TJclSimpleXMLElem);
var
  child , subchild : TjclSimpleXMLElem ;
  FContext : TRttiContext ;
  FType    : TRttiType ;
  FProp    : TRttiProperty ;
  Value    : TValue ;
  MyObj    : TMyBase ;
  FField   : TRttiField ;
  FRecord  : TRttiRecordType ;
  Data     : TValue ;
begin
  FContext := TRttiContext.Create ;
  FType := FContext.GetType ( self.ClassType ) ;
  Child := node.Items.Add ( ClassName ) ;
  for FProp in FType.GetProperties do begin
    if FProp.IsWritable then begin
      case FProp.PropertyType.TypeKind of
        tkClass : begin
          MyObj := TMyBase ( FProp.GetValue ( self ).AsObject ) ;
          MyObj.SaveClass ( Child.Items.Add ( FProp.Name ) , FContext ) ;
          end ;
        tkRecord : begin
          subchild := Child.Items.Add ( FProp.Name ) ;
          FRecord := FContext.GetType(FProp.GetValue(self).TypeInfo).AsRecord ;
          for FField in FRecord.GetFields do begin
            >>> self is not the correct instance <<<
            Value := FField.GetValue ( self ) ;
            subchild.Items.Add ( FField.Name ).Value := Value.ToString ;
            end;
          end ;
        else begin
          Value := FProp.GetValue(self) ;
          Child.Items.Add ( FProp.Name ).Value := Value.ToString ;
          end;
        end;
      end ;
    end ;
  FContext.Free ;
end;
```

I suspect that if I can figure out how to get the values then setting them shouldn't be a problem. Then onto arrays, oh boy!

**Updates:** Please see [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9450928/744588). (Migrated as separate answer to improve visibility).

Comment: Which version of Delphi?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to save "records" in stead of "classes"? if no then do check OmniXML it has the capability of saving and load a TPersistent descendant to/from a *.XML file. http://www.omnixml.com/

Comment: Thanks Dorin I'll look at that. I thought about limiting the supported types but since the existing application already uses a large number of records I wanted to cover records and arrays of records.

Answer (score 12):

I presume you are trying to save the value of a record-typed field of the runtime type of Self, yes?

You have to get the value of the field first, with `FProp.GetValue(Self)`. Let's say you put that in a variable called `FieldValue` of type `TValue`. You can then save the fields of the record value as you wish, though you'll probably want to write a recursive procedure for it, as the fields of the record may themselves be fields. The field getter for records expects the address of the record (a pointer to its start) for symmetry with the setter; the setter expects the address rather than the value because otherwise there would be no easy way to modify a field "in situ" in another class or record, since records are otherwise passed around by value.

You could get that with `FieldValue.GetReferenceToRawData`, which will return a pointer to the start of the records stored inside the `TValue`.

Hopefully this gives you enough clues to continue.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. TMyBase will be the ancestor for future classes and will do the work to read and write those classes. So self is the actual run time object to be saved.

Comment: Do any of you old school people remember the days of Turbo pascal, when you would persist a record by creating a "F:File of MyRecord", assign(F,filename), and then write the binary record content to the file?

Answer (score 5):

**Attribution:** Originally posted as question's updates by the OP ([Mitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390858/mitch)
) - Migrated as separate answer to improve visibility.

**Barry's solution did the trick. Here's the revised code:**

```
    tkRecord : begin
      subchild := Child.Items.Add ( FProp.Name ) ;
      Value := FProp.GetValue(self) ;
      FRecord := FContext.GetType(FProp.GetValue(self).TypeInfo).AsRecord ;
      for FField in FRecord.GetFields do begin
        Data := FField.GetValue ( Value.GetReferenceToRawData ) ;
        subchild.Items.Add ( FField.Name ).Value := Data.ToString ;
        end;
      end ;
```

**For those that need to deal with arrays:**

```
    tkDynArray : begin
      Value := FProp.GetValue ( self ) ;
      FArray := FContext.GetType(Value.TypeInfo) as TRttiDynamicArrayType ;
      subchild := child.Items.Add ( FProp.Name ) ;
      cnt := Value.GetArrayLength ;
      subchild.Properties.Add ( 'Count' , cnt ) ;
      case FArray.ElementType.TypeKind of
        tkInteger ,
        tkFloat   : begin
          for a := 0 to cnt-1 do begin
            Data := Value.GetArrayElement ( a ) ;
            subchild.Items.Add ( IntToStr(a) , Data.ToString ) ;
            end;
          end ;
        tkRecord  : begin
          FRecord := FArray.ElementType as TRttiRecordType ;
          for a := 0 to cnt-1 do begin
            Data := Value.GetArrayElement ( a ) ;
            subsubchild := subchild.Items.Add ( IntToStr(a) ) ;
            for FField in FRecord.GetFields do
              SaveField ( subsubchild , FContext , FField , Data.GetReferenceToRawData ) ;
            end;
          end ;
```